# Unable to use the JWTHelperService in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cordova, jwt

I've initialized a new JWTHELPERSERVICE as:-
`import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';`
and initialized in ngOnInit as

```
const helper = new JwtHelperService();
const responseData = helper.decodeToken(authToken);
```

but when I am building the application getting the foll:- error

```
 Invalid constructor parameter decorator in F:/EPAM/hazardalertmodified/hazardalert/node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/fesm2015/auth0-angular-jwt.js:
 () => [
    { type: undefined, decorators: [{ type: Inject, args: [JWT_OPTIONS,] }] }
]
Error: Error on worker #1: Error: getInternalNameOfClass() called on a non-ES5 class: expected JwtHelperService to have an inner class declaration
    at Esm5ReflectionHost.getInternalNameOfClass (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\host\esm5_host.js:88:23)
    at DelegatingReflectionHost.getInternalNameOfClass (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\host\delegating_host.js:89:34)
    at extractInjectableMetadata (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\annotations\src\injectable.js:125:69)
    at InjectableDecoratorHandler.analyze (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\annotations\src\injectable.js:66:24)
    at NgccTraitCompiler.TraitCompiler.analyzeTrait (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\transform\src\compilation.js:345:40)
    at analyze (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\transform\src\compilation.js:297:58)
    at _loop_1 (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\transform\src\compilation.js:319:21)
    at NgccTraitCompiler.TraitCompiler.analyzeClass (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\transform\src\compilation.js:325:35)
    at NgccTraitCompiler.analyzeFile (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\analysis\ngcc_trait_compiler.js:47:26)
    at DecorationAnalyzer.analyzeProgram (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\analysis\decoration_analyzer.js:134:39)
    at ClusterMaster.onWorkerMessage (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:194:27)
    at F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:54:95
    at ClusterMaster.<anonymous> (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:292:57)
    at step (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:139:27)
    at Object.next (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:120:57)
    at F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:113:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:109:16)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (F:\EPAM\hazardalertmodified\hazardalert\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:286:32)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:310:20)
```

my tsconfig.json  compilerOption is:-

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
```

**Note:-**I am getting this error when doing production build for cordova framework

Comment: Are you using `fontawesome` in your project?

Comment: No I am dont know even what is it .Can u please suggest how to look if I am using fontawesome or not

Comment: search for `fontawesome ` in your package.json file

Comment: its not present in my Package.json

Comment: inside `tsconfig.app.json` file, make this edit: "angularCompilerOptions": {
"enableIvy": false,
}

Comment: I am getting An unhandled exception occurred: Localization with multiple locales in one build is not supported with View Engine.
See "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-UYAcVu\angular-errors.log" for further details.
 if I apply option suggested by you

Comment: Sorry, but this is an another problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside `tsconfig.app.json` file, make this edit:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": { "enableIvy": false, }
```

Then you will get the original problem